# How to use GroupBy more than once in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1

When I try to "group by" more than once, I get an exception error.

In order to isolate the error, I wrote a small piece of code to replicate this exception. It does not intend to achieve anything practical except to use group by more than once and make it work. This is my test code:

```
private IQueryable<Inventory> InventoryMiddleWare1(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var query = _context.Inventory.Where(r => r.InventoryDate>= start && r.InventoryDate<= end)
        .GroupBy(g => new {
            LocationCode = g.LocationCode,
            SKU= g.SKU,
            InventoryDate= g.InventoryDate
        })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            LocationCode = g.Key.LocationCode,
            SKU= g.Key.SKU,
            InventoryDate= g.Key.InventoryDate,
            Units= g.Max(r => r.Units)
        })
        .GroupBy(g => g.InventoryDate).Select(g=> new
        {
            InventoryDate= g.Key.Value,
            Units2= g.Sum(r=>r.Units)
        }).Select(r=> new Inventory()
        {
            InventoryDate= r.InventoryDate,
            Units= r.Units2
        });

        return query;
    }
```

The first message I get is a warning that says:

```
Application> warn: The LINQ expression 'Max()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

Then it crashes and throws the following exception:

```
Application> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
Application>       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
Application> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Found your question whilst having the same problem - I haven't got to the root cause, but do have a workaround... so might be an idea to ***not*** mark this as the 'Accepted Answer'!

Seems there's something stopping you chaining `GroupBy` like this *any more* (I encountered this problem migrating an older code base in which it *did* work)

I got around this by executing the query to a list using `ToList()` after the first one. Of course this may have performance implications for some, but I did say it was a workaround! For the example in the question, my workaround would be:

```
private IQueryable<Inventory> InventoryMiddleWare1(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var query = _context.Inventory.Where(r => r.InventoryDate>= start && r.InventoryDate<= end)
        .GroupBy(g => new {
            LocationCode = g.LocationCode,
            SKU= g.SKU,
            InventoryDate= g.InventoryDate
        })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            LocationCode = g.Key.LocationCode,
            SKU= g.Key.SKU,
            InventoryDate= g.Key.InventoryDate,
            Units= g.Max(r => r.Units)
        })
        .ToList()
        .GroupBy(g => g.InventoryDate).Select(g=> new
        {
            InventoryDate= g.Key.Value,
            Units2= g.Sum(r=>r.Units)
        }).Select(r=> new Inventory()
        {
            InventoryDate= r.InventoryDate,
            Units= r.Units2
        });

        return query;
    }
```

I'll try and follow up when I have some time, but I suspect this is happening because because someone cleverer than me has figured out that one `GroupBy` should always suffice if you frame the query correctly. Would be nice if the exception it threw made sense though!

Comment: Thanks Tim. I also came up with the same workaround before posting this post. But as you said, this has serious performance implications especially in a table as Inventory, that has thousands of items for each SKU and Location for every day. Therefore, this would not be a solution for my problem. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same ArgumentException as Arturo when attempting to use multiple GroupBy clauses in the same query.  A somewhat similar exception described in the following issue, which is supposed to be fixed in EF Core 3.0:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12805

I tried updating my project to EF Core 3.0 preview to see if that resolved my issue.  However, I also had to update to .NET Core 3.0 preview, causing some build/run issues that I didn't have enough time to resolve.